# Запуск второго сайта в nginx

Tags: nginx, debian

На сервере установлена система openmediavault, поэтому в nginx уже запущен один сайт (web панель для управления). Мне необходим еще один сайт для просмотра логов прокси сервера lightsquid. При попытке запустить службу сталкиваюсь с одной и той же ошибкой занятого 80 порта:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-08-13 09:06:13 +05; 5s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 9521 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9522 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

авг 13 09:06:11 NAS systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
авг 13 09:06:11 NAS nginx[9522]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
авг 13 09:06:11 NAS nginx[9522]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
авг 13 09:06:12 NAS nginx[9522]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
авг 13 09:06:12 NAS nginx[9522]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
авг 13 09:06:13 NAS nginx[9522]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
авг 13 09:06:13 NAS nginx[9522]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
авг 13 09:06:13 NAS systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
авг 13 09:06:13 NAS systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
авг 13 09:06:13 NAS systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Ниже конфиги обоих сайтов в nginx:

```
server {
    server_name openmediavault-webgui;
    root /var/www/openmediavault;
    index index.php;
    autoindex off;
    server_tokens off;
    sendfile on;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    client_max_body_size 25M;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/openmediavault-webgui_error.log error;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/openmediavault-webgui_access.log combined;
    error_page 404 = /404.php;
    location /404.html {
        internal;
    }
    location /extjs6/ {
        alias /usr/share/javascript/extjs6/;
        expires 2d;
    }
    location ~ ^/(css|js|images)/ {
        expires 2d;
    }
    location /favicon {
        expires 14d;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm-openmediavault-webgui.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=off;
    include /etc/nginx/openmediavault-webgui.d/*.conf;
}
```

и второй:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    satisfy any;
    allow 192.168.10.0/24;
    deny all;

   # access_log  /var/log/nginx-access.log  main;
   # error_log  /var/log/nginx-error.log info;
    location / {
        root /var/www/lightsquid/lightsquid-1.8/;
        index index.cgi;
    }

    location ~ (\.cgi|\.pl) {
        gzip off;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap/fcgiwrap.lightsquid.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.cgi;
        include "fastcgi_params";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        expires 1m;
        root /var/www/lightsquid/lightsquid-1.8/;
    }
}
```

В конфиге openmediavault есть строчка `listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=off`
Насколько я понимаю, параметр default_server нужно убирать, но это не помогло. Если закомментировать строку, то сервер запустится но сайты работать не будут.

Answer (score 1):

```
server_name _;
```

Замените на полные домены, например site1.lan и site2.lan и добавьте их на днс сервер или в hosts.

default_server уберите

Для запуска в мир нужно купить один или 2 домена: site1.example.com и site2.example.com. Указать их как имена сайтов в nginx.

Бесплатно можно взять домен `.tk` или на сервисах ddns.

Answer (score -2):

Вы пытаетесь запустить два сайта на одном и тоже же сокете (сокет сочетание ip и port). Это невозможно, на 1 порту может работать только 1 сайт

Comment: Я не сильно понимаю, но ведь на nginx можно запустить несколько сайтов. Да сокет у меня один, но какая альтернатива?

Comment: @quasi выбрать другой порт, но будет некрасивый домен с портом на конце, например expample.com:5000. А лучше использовать другой сервер для другого сайта)

Comment: Про виртуальные хосты кто-то не слышал? Днс же есть

Comment: на nginx можно запустить несколько сайтов